# What will be the path of light coming from torch that is lit vertically in a train that is moving at the speed of light compared to the ground?

Tags: experimental-physics, speed-of-light, thought-experiment

Assume a train is moving at the speed of light and a person is sitting in the train with a torch. Say the person lit the torch vertically upward comparing to the ground of the train then after the train travels further distance, from the initial point of lighting the torch will the path of light be inclined? Or how does it will be?

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be a train that travels exactly at the speed of light, since the transformations relating positions and velocities are not well-defined with one coordinate system traveling at the speed of light with respect to the other system.
In other words, it doesn't make sense in special relativity to relate two coordinate frames that have a relative velocity of the speed of light.
Let us thus assume that the train travels at a large speed, close to the speed of light.

The photon emitted from the torch will travel at a constant upward-directed velocity for the observed on the train, then the photon will travel in a diagonal line upwards for the static observer.
The angle of this triangle will depend on the velocity of the train. This is in perfect analogy to the mirror clock which is often evoked when motivating the Lorentz transformation in special relativity.

For more information on the light clock consider [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#/media/File:Time-dilation-002-mod.svg).

Comment: "Torch" in Brittish English means the same as "flashlight" in American English. No flame needed.